# Unity, С# создание вереницы объектов вдоль ширины камеры на равном расстоянии

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем доброго времени суток у меня возникла задача создать ряд объектов(ректенглов) вдоль ширины камеры на равном расстоянии под разные разрешения. По углам камеры тоже должны находится ректенглы Написал скрипт нацепил на камеру ничего не получилось.

```
Vector3 LeftPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
Vector3 RightPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
Vector3 NextPos;
float divideDistansePos;
float minInterval;
int countSpawnerPoint;
public GameObject spawner;

//Расстояние между крайними точками разделить на минимальное 
//получить количество точек, которое может уместиться 
//это кол-во будет не целое число. 
//Затем расстояние разделить на целую часть количества точек, 
//и получить расстояние  на которое нужно смещать точки.


void Start()
{
    //вычисляем расстояние между двумя точками по углам камеры
    divideDistansePos = (Vector3.Distance(LeftPos, RightPos));

    //получаем кол-во точек которые необходимо округлить.
    divideDistansePos /= minInterval;

    //точное число точек
    countSpawnerPoint = (int)Mathf.Round(divideDistansePos);

    divideDistansePos /= countSpawnerPoint;


}

void Generate()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < countSpawnerPoint; i++)
    {
        NextPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(i+divideDistansePos, 1, 0));
        Instantiate(spawner, NextPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Generate();
}
```

Comment: Среди всех комментариев кода, действительности соответствует разве что `// Update is called once per frame` =D

Answer (score 0):

```
void Start() {
    //вычисляем расстояние между двумя точками по углам камеры
    divideDistansePos = Vector3.Distance(LeftPos, RightPos);
    // + расстояние ширины. ( ) лишние

    //получаем кол-во точек которые необходимо округлить.
    divideDistansePos /= minInterval;
    // + Не целочисленное (дробное) значение

    //точное число точек
    countSpawnerPoint = (int)Mathf.Round(divideDistansePos);
    // + точное? o_O Целочисленное значение!
    // + Для этого есть Mathf.RoundToInt();

    divideDistansePos /= countSpawnerPoint;
    // + float/int = int !!!   float/(float)int = float !!! Умножения тоже касается
    // + Не целочисленное значение делим на тоже самое, но целочесленное чтобы получить 1... WTF?
    // + Генератор случайного кода? Любим гусей через парадоксальную абстракцию?
}

void Generate () {
    for (int i = 0; i < countSpawnerPoint; i++) {
        NextPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(i+divideDistansePos, 1, 0));
        // + Viewport нормализован! Диапазон значений от 0f до 1f, как ты и указывал LeftPos и RightPos
        // + i+divideDistansePos #№& Снова генератор? Сам то понял что оно делает?
        Instantiate(spawner, NextPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

void Update () {
    Generate();
    // + Нахрена это делается каждый кадр?
}
```

И в общем и целом весь план перехват с `Viewport` полная хрень.

У камеры есть поле `Size` и этот `Size`*2f в 2D есть высота экрана в сцене, а через отношение `Screen.width` и `Screen.height` можно узнать и ширину (они кстате `int` не накосяч опять с делением).

Я понял, что ты паршиво считаешь (умножаешь и делишь) и путаешь `int` и `float`, но научиться нужео, потому что в переди ещё придётся разбираться с окружностью (Sin и Cos);

Тупо пробуй много раз. И ещё пользуйся `Debug.Log()`, чтобы понимать чё там у тебя навычислялось (к примеру `divideDistansePos`).

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Используй компонент `Grid Layout Group` для матрицы или `Vertical/Horizontal Layout Group`. Там задаешь размеры ячеек, расстояние между ними и все такое, закидываешь в объект с этим компонентом дочерние и вуаля, они на одинаковом расстоянии. Все находится на `Canvas` и поэтому будет скейлиться по экрану.

Comment: Благодарю, попробую

Comment: @BBadger если что - на связи

Comment: Я забыл сказать самое важное. В зависимости от разрешения экрана определяется число элементов, то бишь объектов. К примеру для планшетов объектов вдоль ширины будет больше, чем для смартфонов. В Grid Layout Group, насколько я понял нужно определить точное чилсо. А тут получается значение определяется разрешением.